# Преобразование коллекции типизированной классом оберткой в массив значений примитивов

Tags: java

Собственно есть:

```
ArrayList<Byte> bytes = ...
```

Надо преобразовать в:

```
byte[] lol = ...
```

понятно что можно как то так:

```
        byte[] lol = new byte[bytes.size()];
        int inclol = 0;
        for (Byte b : bytes) {
            lol[inclol] = b.byteValue();
            inclol++;
        }
```

Такой код нормой считается что ли? или есть какой-то сахар для аналогичных ситуаций, который я проворонил? :) Понятно что нельзя привести типизированную коллекцию к массиву сразу, но вот почему Byte[] (полученный от коллекции) к byte[] не приводится даже как то странно... autoboxing игнорирует эту ситуацию, статических методов в util я не нашел... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Byte> bytes= new ArrayList<Byte>();
byte[] b= ArrayUtils.toPrimitive( bytes.toArray(new Byte[bytes.size()]) );
```

Правда ArrayUtils нет в JRE.

Comment: apache commons тоже пойдет, там так много полезного, что его можно считать нативной явой :)

Comment: Самое смешное, что [в исходниках ArrayUtils](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.java#ArrayUtils.toPrimitive%28java.lang.Byte%5B%5D%29) - все решается прямым перебором массива :)

Answer (score 0):

`Byte[]` и `byte[]` - это разные типы. Один не является оберткой для другого. Auto boxing/unboxing применим только к примитивным типам и их врапперам.

И кстати, получить массив элементов из `ArrayList`'а можно с помощью метода [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T[]%29).

Comment: ну да я написал же что в курсе про toArray, но он вернет либо массив Byte[] либо массив Object[], Byte обертка byte, я ожидал какого-то сахара и для их массивов, но не нашел :)